# How do I define xaml content (stackpanel with content) as an application resource?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, controls, app.xaml, application-resource

I'm sure this question is elementary understanding of Silverlight and has probably been asked several times before, but I'm having trouble finding search terms for what I'm looking for.

In several views I have to implement something visual to warn the user that there's no connection. What I want to do is define a stackpanel or grid with content, that I can use in several views. I want to have a central place to define how it appears in all my views. So if I want to add an illustration I only have to do that one place.

```
<StackPanel>
   <Image />
   <TextBlock Text="No WIFI etc. etc." />
</StackPanel>
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

You should put these things into a `UserControl` and then reference the `UserControl` whenever you need the content